# WebBrowser Copy/SelectAll Command not working C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, richtextbox

I've came across the following way to convert a HTML Document into RTF in C#.

```cs
private static byte[] HtmlDocumentToRtfBytes(string html)
{
    var rtbTemp = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
    var wb = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
    wb.Navigate("");

    var doc = wb.Document.OpenNew(true); 
    doc.Write(html); 

    wb.Refresh(); 
    wb.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
    wb.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);

    rtbTemp.SelectAll();
    rtbTemp.Paste();

    return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rtbTemp.Rtf);
}
```

But unfortunately there seems to be an issue with the WebBrowser when either executing the "SelectAll" or "Copy" command, since when I check the contents of the RichTextBox it only contains the things I had in my clipboard before executing the program.

The method is run inside a COM Add-In for Microsoft Outlook. The .NET Version is 4.7.2

Comment: Isn't SelectAll and Copy executing a macro on the original webpage?

Comment: @jdweng Yes, and it should fill the clipboard with the contents of the page

Comment: If you are using a different URL the new URL may not have those commands.

Comment: @jdweng The URL is about:blank

Comment: You do not have a URL so the two commands do not exist.  What is the original URL.

Comment: `wb.Navigate(""); var doc = wb.Document.OpenNew(true); doc.Write(html); wb.Refresh(); /* then the rest */` -- You have to add that RichTextBox to a Container, right? The code you posted here creates a Control and then leaves it stranded in a limbo. Unless you just want to read the RTF out of it. But, for testing, I suggest you show it somewhere.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it doesn't change anything. When debugging the wb object I can already see that that the HTML is loaded correctly. Any other ideas?

Comment: The code I've posted is now tested. It works as intended. Post the HTML you're writing to the Document. Make sure you have the HTML5 header there and this: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` in `<HEAD>`

Comment: @Jimi since the HTML code is very long I put it into a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/kbcuHGj3

Comment: Tested. Without any change to the HTML. Works as expected. -- If you used the code I posted here exactly as it is and it still doesn't work for you, then describe a little better how / when this code is executed, the .Net version in use etc.

Comment: @Jimi I've updated the initial question with the full code and details. And just for sanity sake did I create a brand new console application testing just this details... still no result. Entire ConsoleApp: https://pastebin.com/S7RDuGti

Comment: Tested your code as it is, both .Net 4.7.2 and 4.8 (these Controls are actually the same version in both Frameworks, but...) and no problem found. As a note, you should not be  using a Thread like that and get the bytes with `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` -- This is the [recording of the run](https://imgur.com/LSTQVTV).

Comment: @Jimi This is so strange, I tested the EXACT same code. https://imgur.com/a/J711pWZ

Comment: Well, I cannot reproduce it. I also turned on Clipboard History (Windows 10) to check whether it could interfere with this operation, but it doesn't. -- Try to remove the Thread (which doesn't seem to be needed at all here), the WebBrowser Control (IE) doesn't exactly like it setup in that way, see if you get better results. It shouldn't matter with this simple code in a Console app, but better test it.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks I found the solution, it was related to my internet settings in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you need to enable programmatic access to the clipboard in your IE Internet Settings.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm3X2.png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).